# How to declare Zend_Db_Table_Row database table?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have the following zendframework model classes

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Mobile extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

protected $_name = 'mobile';
protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_Mobile';
}
```

Object Class

```
class Application_Model_Mobile extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {



}
```

But when I try to save directly from o Application Model_Mobile it returns an error

```
 $m = new Application_Model_Mobile();
 $m->name = 'Mobile Test';
 $m->save();

 Application error
 Exception information:

 Message: Specified column "chave" is not in the row
```

How could I tell Application_Model_Celular has mobile table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
class Application_Model_Mobile extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract {
     protected $_tableClass = 'Application_Model_DbTable_Mobile';


}
```

Normally you wouldn't use Zend_Db this way (although you may have a perfectly good reason to).  The standard way to do this would be to not define the Application_Model_Mobile class and just write the code as:

```
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_Mobile();
$m = $table->createRow();
$m->name = 'Mobile Test';
$m->save();
```

Comment: Declare variable $_tableClass still doesn't work :( Yeah I may use like it if that's the one way.